# How to periodically update SQL Server table from an Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, auto-update, ssms-2014

For my .NET Application I have an Excel file that is used as the data source. This Excel file is updated every hour. My current back-end database technology is MS Access. The Access file has a linked table to the mentioned Excel file. I would like to switch over my back-end to SQL Server.

My question is how can I create a linked table in SQL Server such that I always have the current data in my SQL Server database. Right now I have managed to import the Excel sheet through the import wizard in SQL Server Mgmt. Studio. But obviously this is static (not updated hourly like the excel sheet).

Can I create some sort of procedure that runs every hour, reads the Excel sheet and import to my SQL Server database? How would I go about doing that? Or any other method as long as my table in SQL Server gets updated on an hourly basis with data from the Excel sheet.

Comment: There are several different ways you can do this.  I suggest you start by researching the topic using your Google Fu.  Some areas of interest might be SQL Agent, OPENROWSET and Linked Server to Excel.  You could also do this outside of SQL using another language, like C#.  There are a bunch of different possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

One, do not code read "in process" from the excel file.  That is a disaster waiting to happen.  Some user opens the file, locks it, and now your sql-server starts failing.  :)   That is a bad scenario.

You should create an ETL package to run (hourly)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-ver15

> What is SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)? MicrosoftSQL Server

> Integration Services (SSIS) is a platform for building
> high-performance data integration solutions, including extraction,
> transformation, and load (ETL) packages for data warehousing. SSIS
> includes graphical tools and wizards for building and debugging
> packages; tasks for performing workflow functions such as FTP
> operations, executing SQL statements, and sending e-mail messages;
> data sources and destinations for extracting and loading data;
> transformations for cleaning, aggregating, merging, and copying data;
> a management database, SSISDB, for administering package execution and
> storage; and application programming interfaces (APIs) for programming
> the Integration Services object model.

**data sources and destinations for extracting and loading data;**

Deploy and Schedule:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9069/deploy-and-schedule-an-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-step-by-step/

> Scheduling the SSIS Package with SQL Server Agent
> Manually executing packages is one thing, but normally you will schedule packages so your ETL can run in a specific time windows
> (probably at night). The easiest option is SQL Server Agent. You can
> right-click on the Jobs node to create a new job:

[image]